# Convert datetime to Time and show in a label in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view in which I have a label in which I want to show the date and time as

**Nov 19 at  07:30 am**

i have a field in the database which give the datetime value as  **2011-11-19 07:30:43.193**

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd") + " at " +
                   DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

This is the closest you can get. This will supply the FULL NAME for the month (MMMM) -
you can select the 1st 3 letters if you would like.

Comment: And of course, you can use `string.Format("{0} at {1}", ..., ...)` to get even more readable code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

to grids column in which u binding date from database use following attribute

```
DataFormatString="{0:MMM dd 'at' hh:mm tt}"
```